# Objective C exc_BAD_ACCESS infinite loop how to fix?

Tags: exc-bad-access, objective-c++

hi Guys i am new to objective C. I am trying to integrate an existing code with 3rd party SDK and functionality. It goes into infinite loop.

```
 NSError *iOSCdmHost::CreateSession(Cdm::SessionType sessionType,
                                       NSString **sessionIdStr) {
      std::string sessionId;
      Cdm::Status code = cdm_->createSession(sessionType, &sessionId);
      if (code != Cdm::kSuccess) {
        return GetErrorFromStatus(code, @"Error creating session.");
      }

  *sessionIdStr = [NSString stringWithStdString:sessionId];
  return nil;
}
```

It is failing at this line.
 Cdm::Status code = cdm_->createSession(sessionType, &sessionId);

Comment: You have infinite recursion and we need more context plus at least a partial stack trace.

Comment: There is no infinite recursion in that code as `CreateSession() != createSession()`.

Comment: Have you gotten anywhere with this? I've tried disabling dead code stripping but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue and I haven't solved it fully. Mine is working in the simulator fine. its also working fine for non encrypted content. So I think the problem lies in library for device.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/widevine-ios-discuss/rfagTiZTdqc

Edit 
The answer is this - dead Code stripping in build setting should be set to 'no'